# how to replace table buttons with divs

Tags: html, canvas-lms

I'm trying to convert this table to divs to create a homepage for an online course. Can someone help me style the banner image and buttons in divs instead of a table? Here's the sample code:

```
<table class="tg" style="width: 785.948px;" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="tg-baqh" style="width: 726.948px;" colspan="5"><img src="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/files/187001/preview" alt="TBLE banner-2.png" width="808" height="166" data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/files/187001" data-api-returntype="File" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-6k2t" style="width: 130px; text-align: center;"><a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="width: 141px; height: 21px;" title="Before We Meet" href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11024" data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11024" data-api-returntype="Module">Link 1</a></td>
<td class="tg-6k2t" style="width: 130px; text-align: center;"><a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="width: 135px; height: 21px;" title="Wk 1: Discover" href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11025" data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11025" data-api-returntype="Module">Link 2</a></td>
<td class="tg-6k2t" style="width: 130px; text-align: center;"><a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="width: 141px; height: 21px;" title="Wk 2: Design" href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11026" data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11026" data-api-returntype="Module">Link 3</a></td>
<td class="tg-6k2t" style="width: 130px; text-align: center;"><a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="width: 141px; height: 21px;" title="Week 3: Deliver" href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11027" data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11027" data-api-returntype="Module">Link 4</a></td>
<td class="tg-6k2t" style="width: 130px; text-align: center;"><a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="width: 141px; height: 21px;" title="Week 3: Deliver" href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11027" data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11027" data-api-returntype="Module">Link 5</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why won't you change every `td` to `div` and remove everything around?

Comment: A lot would also depend upon the class settings you are using but neglected to supply.

Answer (score 0):

Just SWAGing your layout with the magic of Flex and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<title> Test Page </title>
<!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" media="screen" -->
<style>
 .tg { width: 785.948px; }
 .tg-bagh { width: 726.948px; }
 .tg-6k2t { width: 130px; text-align: center; }
 a { width: 135px; height: 21px; }

 .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0.2em;
    padding: 0.2em;
 }
 .wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0.2em;
    padding: 0.2em;
 }

/*
 FileName -     styles.css
 Description -  CSS code for making the image responsive by setting the value of four properties
                such as display, margin-left, margin-right, width
 Author -       Tanu Nanda Prabhu
*/
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

</head><body>

<div class="tg-baqh center">
 <img src="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/files/187001/preview"
  alt="TBLE banner-2.png"
  width="100%" height="166"
  data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/files/187001"
  data-api-returntype="File" />
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="tg-6k2t">
  <a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary"
  title="Before We Meet"
  href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11024"
  data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11024"
  data-api-returntype="Module">Link 1</a>
 </div>

 <div class="tg-6k2t">
  <a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary"
  title="Wk 1: Discover"
  href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11025"
  data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11025"
  data-api-returntype="Module">Link 2</a>
 </div>

 <div class="tg-6k2t">
  <a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary"
  title="Wk 2: Design"
  href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11026"
  data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11026"
  data-api-returntype="Module">Link 3</a>
 </div>

 <div class="tg-6k2t">
  <a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary"
  title="Week 3: Deliver"
  href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11027"
  data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11027"
  data-api-returntype="Module">Link 4</a>
 </div>

 <div class="tg-6k2t">
  <a id="" class="btn btn-small btn-primary"
  title="Week 3: Deliver"
  href="https://canvas.ubc.ca/courses/1755/modules/11027"
  data-api-endpoint="https://canvas.ubc.ca/api/v1/courses/1755/modules/11027"
  data-api-returntype="Module">Link 5</a>
 </div>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Could be made more responsive if you had defined more of your existing CSS
Removed all inline CSS statements for a start.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without CSS (sorry, I'm completely new to this and learning on the fly). It's for a page in the Canvas LMS, and I'm not able to load custom CSS. Would it involve HTML in-line styling, instead? I'm trying to line the buttons up in a row horizontally underneath the banner picture.